# Laplace transform of piecewise function with 3 parts

Tags: laplace-transform

How to solve the question like this?

$f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      1 & 1\leq t <3 \\
      te^{-3t} & 4\leq t < 5 \\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}
$

I need to consider 4 cases? Which is $0<t \leq 1$, $1 \leq t < 3$, $ 4 \leq t < 5 $ and $t > 5$?

Comment: Have you ever heard about Heaviside step function?

Comment: Remember that $u(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$, and $=1$ for $t \geq 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Write your function in terms of the Heaviside Step Function, i.e, $f(t) = 1\,[u(t-1)-u(t-3)]+te^{-3t}\,[u(t-4)-u(t-5)]$.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to ask, how to compute the Laplace transform of the step function?